# Make Windows 10 Quick Launch use two rows

Tags: windows-10

I am running Windows 10. I recently reformatted and reinstalled my OS. I can't recreate the Quick Launch toolbar that I had previously. Specifically, I can't get the Quick Launch toolbar to use both rows of the taskbar. See photo below of the old setup and the new setup.

**old Quick Launch ↓**
[image: old Quick Launch]

**new Quick Launch ↓**
[image: new Quick Launch]

**new Quick Launch with expected locations of Quick Launch icons ↓**
[image: new Quick Launch with examples]

**NB:** The taskbar buttons (illustrated as Button 1 and Button 2) do populate to 2 rows as expected. It is the Quick Launch icons (illustrated as 4, 5, 6) that do not populate to the second row.

I've counted the pixels and they are the same. And I'm 99% sure I am using the same Display Settings (native 2560 x 1440; 100% scale). I remember struggling to get the Quick Launch to use both rows previously, but I can't remember the solution. I've tried turning off "Use small taskbar buttons" in the Taskbar settings, and this results in two rows, but the rows, buttons, and taskbar are much bigger with those settings (and don't match my "old Quick Launch" photos above). Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: OK, so I look like an idiot, but after posting that question I restarted my computer (for reasons not related to the Quick Access issue), and now I suddenly have two rows. I didn't change any settings, install any drivers, anything. I guess that explains why I can't remember how I fixed it last time [sigh]

Comment: How do you get Quick Access as a Toolbar? When I try Taskbar right-click > Toolbars > New > select Quick Access (but only in the dialog NavPane), I get an error.

Comment: Sorry, not Quick Access, Quick Launch. I used this to add the Quick Launch toolbar: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4624-add-remove-quick-launch-toolbar-windows-10-a.html. I've corrected my question.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Taskbar and select Unlock. Once unlocked, move your cursor to the top of the Taskbar so that is turns into a double arrow.

You can change the height of the Taskbar with the double arrow. Be sure to lock the Taskbar afterward

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. The Taskbar buttons (one of them is whited out in the "new Quick Access" image) form two rows as expected. It is the Quick Access icons that are not forming two rows. I'll edit the image to show what I mean.